# RequestMappingHandlerMapping and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I use Spring Boot.

I have a class that uses RequestMappingHandlerMapping injected into it.

```
class Foo {
    private final RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping;

    Foo(RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping) {
      this.mapping = mapping;
    }
}
```

I have a configuration that spits out Foo and RequestMappingHandlerMapping as beans.

```
@Configuration
class Bar extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Foo foo(){
       return new Foo(requestMappingHandlerMapping());
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping(){
       return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    }
}
```

And lastly I have one more class that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

```
@Configuration
class Baz extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(<some interceptor>).addPathPatterns(URL_PATTERN);
    }
}
```

What I notice is that because of the RequestMappingHandlerMapping, my interceptor does ***not*** get registered. My interceptor gets registered when I comment out RequestMappingHandlerMapping or when I change Baz such that it extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport.

Not sure entirely what can cause this. Because of this the super classes of RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter also doesn't get registered. Can someone help me out by explaining the reason for this behaviour?

What I also notice is that if I put @EnableWebMvc in the Baz class where the interceptor is registered, then it does get registered. But unfortunately, any POST request to the controllers return 415 instead of 201. My controllers are annotated with @RestController and use media type hal+json.

Comment: Are you using Spring-boot?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix part of the problem which was caused by @EnableWebMvc causing POST to return 415 instead of 201

```
@Configuration
class Baz extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(<some interceptor>).addPathPatterns(URL_PATTERN);
   }

   @Override
   public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>converters) {
   converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
   }
}
```

It looks like everything is in place now : RequestMappingHandlerMapping is getting picked up and the interceptors are also registered properly.